# Redirection conflicts between Wordpress and other root folders

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

My question is quite tricky.
I have a Wordpress install running on root folder with the Website URL setting: `www.domain.com` and languages like `http://www.domain.com/fr/`
I also have other hard coded folders in root directory such as /order/ or /auth/ that I would like users to access on https without www so `https://domain.com` with langages like `https://domain.com/fr/auth/` (where /auth/ is the hard coded folder).
However it's redirecting me to `https://www.domain.com/fr/auth/`.
If I choose non-www URL for everything I get a Wordpress 404 page while trying to access my hard coded folder.

Long story short, is there a way to avoid wordpress redirection if we use https so we can access other root hard coded folders or using some htaccess rules?

My htaccess at the moment is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/auth/$ /auth/?lang=$1 [L]
```

Been trying to come up with a solution for the architecture since a week. Thanks for your help!

Comment: First thing you need to do is move your auth rule **before** wordpress rules **not** after. The wordpress rules are setup to redirect everything to index.php.  Then removing www and use https is just a matter of adding another rule for that also above the wordpress rules.

Comment: It works !!!!!!!!!! Thanks a lot @PanamaJack you the man!